# Pycryptodome error when running on Debian with Python 3.10

Tags: python, debian, python-3.10

I'm trying to run my project in WSL since I have Windows specific errors in it.  So I installed Debian, build/installed Python 3.10 from source, and used `update-alternatives` to link it to `python3`.

When I run the program however, I get this error.  It seems to be looking for a compiled file in `dist-packages`, when it wouldn't be there since `python3.10-cryptodome` doesn't exist on debian apt yet.

I tried just running `pip3.10 install cryptodome` but that changed nothing.

How can I get this module to work properly with Python 3.10 on debian?

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/cclloyd/blahblah/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
  File "/home/mendicant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yt_dlp/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .options import parseOpts
  File "/home/mendicant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yt_dlp/options.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import (
  File "/home/mendicant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yt_dlp/compat.py", line 166, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES as compat_pycrypto_AES
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py", line 34, in <module>
    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb", """
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Util/_raw_api.py", line 258, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
    raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Trying '_raw_ecb.abi3.so': /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Trying '_raw_ecb.so': /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```